# Can WordPress sites be updated with a CVS from local to live?

Tags: wordpress, uploading, file-manager

I regularly use the theme editor or FTP live files onto my local server (and load them into Visual Studio), but this can be time consuming when I need to **debug** many files.

Is there a more efficient way to update a WordPress system other than these methods? Can a CVS be integrated easily to upload changed files?

Comment: Why don't you debug your website in local with a web server like Apache?

Comment: to add: I typically install and work from a "live" server that is locked down. So perhaps my workflow process is causing my headache...

Comment: Also, this comes into play more with setups that are already online and I need to do maintenance.

Such as a the current site I am dealing with and there is only a live version from which I have to now FTP files over in order to fix bugs.

Comment: You can download the site on your computer and debug it easily. Then, you upload files when a bug is fixed or new features is available.

Comment: This is my current process. It is time consuming as it stands. I'm not sure there is another way around this so my question still remains unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have FTP access, you might be able to use something like `git-ftp` to push the changes up to live after you have tested/debugged them locally: https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp.

Use WP Migrate DB to get a copy of the live database: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/.

Setup a local copy with XAMPP or MAMPP, whatever, make your changes, then commit the changes to git and push them live with `git-ftp`.